Difference between these two equations to calculate uncertainty when multiplying
I have seen these 2 equations for how to calculate the uncertainty when 2 numbers (that have uncertainty) are multiplied.
$$(A\pm a)\times(B\pm b)=(A\times B)\pm \left[\left(\frac{a}{A}\cdot100\right)+\left(\frac{b}{B}\cdot100\right)\right]\%$$
With a very beautiful proof here.
But I have also seen this more "correct" formula:
$$
\frac{\sigma_f}{f} = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_A^2}{A^2} +  \frac{\sigma_B^2}{B^2} + 2 \frac{\sigma_{AB}}{AB}}.
$$
I have seen the proof of this error propagation formula, but unfortunately, my physics/maths knowledge is stuck at a high school level so I don't really understand it (I regrettably did not study STEM in University).
But my main question is, why is the first equation a mere approximation? What's wrong with the proof linked here? It looks quite valid to me. Why is the proper/more accurate error propagation formula different?

The first equation is not an approximation, it's a conditional equation.
The condition is that the errors, $a$ and $b$, are uncorrelated.
It might be simpler to first work it out with addition. Suppose I measure 2 quantities--lengths, call them lengths, $A, B$ relative to some origin, with $N$ samples each. Suppose they have gaussian random error with standard deviations $\sigma_A, \sigma_B$.
So our set of measurements is:
$$ A_j, B_j;\ \ \ \ \ j=(1, \ldots, N)$$
which means and uncertainties are:
$$ \bar A \pm \frac{\sigma_A}{\sqrt N} \equiv \bar A \pm \sigma_{\bar A} $$
$$ \bar B \pm \frac{\sigma_B}{\sqrt N}\equiv \bar B \pm \sigma_{\bar B}  $$
We want to know the separation, $L=A-B$, between $A$ and $B$.
Our measurement is:
$$ \langle L \rangle = (\bar A - \bar B) \pm \sigma_L $$
If the Gaussian random errors are uncorrelated, meaning:
$$ \langle a_i b_i \rangle \rightarrow 0;\ \ \ \ N\rightarrow \infty
$$
where the $a_i, b_i$ are the individual measurement uncertainties.
In our model:
$$   \langle a_i b_i \rangle = \sigma_A\sigma_B  \langle n^{(a)}_i n^{(b)}_i \rangle  $$
where the $n^{(a,b)}_i$ are uncorrelated normal Gaussian random numbers, and the expectation of their product is indeed zero. Hence:
$$ \sigma^2_L = \sigma_{\bar A}^2 + \sigma_{\bar B}^2 $$
If you're learning this, this is a really good time to use your favorite software (python) and just generate some distributions and and look at the standard deviations of difference, correlations, and convergence with $N$.
Note that if $n^{(a)}_i = n^{(b)}_i$ (complete correlation), they cancel in the $L_i = A_i - B_i$ so the estimated error is zero.
Now you may say: but what if the measured difference in $L_j$ is not constant for different $j$? Well, then your error model is wrong and you get results that can't be interpreted properly.
Suppose you generate 3 sets of random numbers
($ m^{(a)}_i,m^{(b)}_i, n'_i$) and share one to model correlated random errors, i.e.:
$$ n^{(a)}_i = \frac{m^{(a)}_i + C n'_i}{\sqrt{1 + C^2}} $$
$$ n^{(b)}_i = \frac{m^{(b)}_i + C n'_i}{\sqrt{1 + C^2}} $$
then you will find that:
$$ \sigma^2_L = \sigma^2_{\bar A} + \sigma^2_{\bar B} -2C_{AB} \sigma_{\bar A}\sigma_{\bar B}$$
where
$$ C_{AB} = \frac{C^2}{1+C^2} $$
is the coefficient-of-correlation between $a_i, b_i$, and has this form because I made a poor choice of definitions.
I strongly recommend using your favorite software (python, numpy) to go investigate. If you (scatter) plot $b_i$ vs  $a_i$ you get a circle/tilted ellipse/line for un-/partial/total correlations. No eclipse pun intended. (and by circle I mean disk with a Gaussian density, and like-wise for the ellipse, but the circle may be an ellipse (though not tilted) if $\sigma_A \ne \sigma_B$).
